# Unpivot Several Columns to Result in Two

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I receive data that looks like this:

| Name | 01/01/2023 | 01/02/2023 | Revenue | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chris | 1 | 3 | £100 | £300 |
| Colin | 5 | 8 | £500 | £800 |
| Pete | 2 | 5 | £200 | £500 |

Where name is self-explanatory, the next two columns are dates (in UK format) with the number of days worked in the period shown below, and the final two columns are revenue.

I want to modify this data in Power Query so it looks like this:

| Name | Date | Work Days | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chris | 01/01/2023 | 1 | £100 |
| Chris | 01/02/2023 | 3 | £300 |
| Colin | 01/01/2023 | 5 | £500 |
| Colin | 01/02/2023 | 8 | £800 |
| Pete | 01/01/2023 | 2 | £200 |
| Pete | 01/02/2023 | 5 | £500 |

I thought this would be some kind of a pivot operation but I can't figure it out.

Any assistance will be gratefully received.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way:

- Using `List.Generate`, create a List of Tables using each Date/Revenue Pair.
- For each of the tables, ensure the Revenue Column is named Revenue (and not Revenue2, Revenu3, etc) and then `Unpivot` the table.
- Then expand the column that has the list of tables
- The rest is "housekeeping"

***Code Edited to provide for varying numbers of "First Columns" to be retained before the sets of Date and Revenue columns***

*Change **#"Retained Column Count"** to reflect that number of Columns

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    colNames = List.Buffer(Table.ColumnNames(Source)),

//How many columns at the beginning are non data pairs
    #"Retained Column Count" = 4,

    #"First Columns" = List.FirstN(colNames,#"Retained Column Count"),
    #"Date Columns" = List.Range(colNames,#"Retained Column Count",(List.Count(colNames)-#"Retained Column Count")/2),
    #"Revenue Columns" = List.LastN(colNames,List.Count(#"Date Columns")),

//set data types
    types = List.Transform(#"First Columns", each {_, type text}) &
            List.Transform(#"Date Columns", each {_, Int64.Type}) &
            List.Transform(#"Revenue Columns", each {_, Currency.Type}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, types, "en-GB"),

//create a list of tables consisting of each date/revenue pair
// then unpivot each table
// ensure Revenue column has the same name throughout
    #"Data Pairs" = List.Generate(
        ()=>[t=Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",#"First Columns" & {#"Date Columns"{0}} & {#"Revenue Columns"{0}}), idx=0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(#"Date Columns"),
            each [t=Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",#"First Columns" & {#"Date Columns"{[idx]+1}} & {#"Revenue Columns"{[idx]+1}}), idx=[idx]+1],
            each Table.Unpivot(
                    Table.RenameColumns([t], {Table.ColumnNames([t]){#"Retained Column Count"+1},"Revenue"}),
                        {#"Date Columns"{[idx]}},"Date","Work Days")),

//to a table
//  then combine the tables with column names in desired order
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Data Pairs", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", #"First Columns" & {"Date","Work Days","Revenue"}),
  
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1", 
        List.Transform(#"First Columns", each {_, type text})  &
        {{"Date", type date},
        {"Work Days", Int64.Type},
        {"Revenue", Currency.Type}}, "en-GB"),
        
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type with Locale",{{"Name", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. I very nearly have it working but I'm wondering what I would need to modify if there were 18 data pairs?

Comment: @OuluChris So long as the format of your table is the same, `|Name|Date1|Date2|Date3|Date4|...|Revenue1|Revenue2|Revenue3|Revenue4|...`, you shouldn't have to modify anything. What problem are you having?

Comment: My apologies, you're correct, it does work. Between posting the question and trying out this answer I modified the source so that it was in the format |Name|Date1|Revenue1|Date2|Revenue2|...etc. With the data in the original format, it works perfectly. Could this be modified to adapt to the new format?

Comment: @OuluChris Yes. It's just a matter of changing the pointers in the `List.Generate` function so they point to the correct columns.  I'll add the change as an edit.

Comment: My sincere apologies, but I decided the first data format was better. It might not necessarily be better for modelling but it's better for user data input. In addition, the actual first four columns are | Name | Technical Grade | Staff Team | Discipline | and I need to figure out how to retain these first four columns before starting to build the data pairs. (I stripped them out of the original because I thought this would be a pivot operation and I'd understand how to add them back but I don't in this example)

Comment: @OuluChris Then the principal would be the same as the first example. Except you remove the first four column names and then add them back on when you are selecting columns in the list generate function.

Comment: @OuluChris See latest edit. All you should need to do is change the `#"Retained Column Count"` line to reflect the number of columns. If what you describe in you last post is truly the case, you would replace the `1` with a `4`

Comment: This (a direct copy and paste with 4 substituted for 1) works as far down the Applied Steps as Data Pairs. At that point the List it generates shows errors in each of the four rows. The List Generate in the Data Pairs step is far too complicated for me to figure out even after sitting here for a couple of hours and Googling each of the terms. Could I please have a tiny bit more of your incredibly valuable advice?

Comment: @OuluChris Found the problem. I had hard-coded a particular element for a certain number of columns and neglected to recode it to vary with `#"Retained Column Count"`. Code in answer is edited.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Set0=List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1),
Set1= List.Combine({Set0,List.Alternate(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1,1)}),
Set2=List.Combine({Set0,List.Alternate(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1),1,1)}),
Part1 = Table.SelectColumns(Source,Set1),
Part2 = Table.SelectColumns(Source,Set2),
Date1 = Table.AddColumn(Part1,"Date" , each Table.ColumnNames(Part1){1}),
Date2 = Table.AddColumn(Part2,"Date" , each Table.ColumnNames(Part2){1}),
Rename1 = Table.RenameColumns(Date1,{{Table.ColumnNames(Part1){2}, "Revenue"}, {Table.ColumnNames(Part1){1}, "Work Days"}}),
Rename2 = Table.RenameColumns(Date2,{{Table.ColumnNames(Part2){2}, "Revenue"}, {Table.ColumnNames(Part2){1}, "Work Days"}}),
combined = Rename1 & Rename2
in combined
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index", "Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Date", each if Text.Start([Attribute],3)="Rev" then null else [Attribute]),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "count", each if Text.Start([Attribute],3)="Rev" then null else [Value]),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Index.1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index1", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index.1], 2), type number),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Inserted Modulo",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}, {"Modulo", Order.Ascending}, {"Attribute", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows",{"Date", "count"}),
x=Table.AlternateRows(#"Filled Down",0,1,1),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(x,{"Name", "Value", "Date", "count"})
in  #"Removed Other Columns"
```